# Counting likes and comments between two different table of a specific topic

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I have two tables, **likes** and **comments** both of which refer to topic posts - like a topic of a forum for example.

Both of them have a column that refers to a specific topic_id.

Now here's the deal: i want to create a top 5 chart of most liked + commented, the total of both summed up i mean, topics.

For example i did this query for selecting from the topics table the most liked, i want to make the same chart with the total of likes + comments. Here's my top 5 topics by total of likes only.

```
SELECT topics.* ,
COUNT(q_id)
AS post_count 
FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN likes 
ON topics.id = likes.q_id 
WHERE topics.to_user = 'someuser' 
GROUP BY likes.q_id  
ORDER BY post_count DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: tnx for help, i just edited my ask in order to give more informations, i'll try post my db in ddl format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.id, count(comments.id) + count(likes.id) AS score 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id 
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id 
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY score desc;
```

For those interested here's the solution.

Comment: This may produce wrong score when actual comments count and likes count are not equal. Double `LEFT JOIN` will produce duplicated entry to 'fill the gap'. You can try selecting a post with 2 likes and 1 comment. The result score will be 4 instead of 3. To solve this, add `DISTINCT` to your count parameter: `count(DISTINCT comments.id) + count(DISTINCT likes.id)`

Comment: This will not give correct count with out DISTINCT keyword. I mean count(DISTINCT(comments.id)) + count(DISTINCT(likes.id)) AS score .

Answer (score 1):

This will works like a charm!!

```
      SELECT topics.id
            ,count(DISTINCT(comments.id)) + count(DISTINCT(likes.id)) AS score 
      FROM topics
      LEFT JOIN comments ON topics.id = comments.post_id 
      LEFT JOIN likes ON topics.id = likes.post_id 
      WHERE topics.to_user = 'someuser' 
      GROUP BY topics.id 
      ORDER BY score desc 
      LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT likes.topic_id, comments.topic_id FROM likes,comments WHERE comments.topic_id = likes.topic_id AND likes.topic_id=[topicid]
```

That would return only the rows where the ids matched. Then you would just count rows. In php you would use: mysql_num_rows()

Comment: Er, that's not going to help !?!

Comment: mmm actually it didn't help, i want to order the topics ( in another table called topics) with best likes + comments counting, directly on the sql query, i'll post the ddl soon, maybe it'll be useful. tnx.

Comment: Not sure why the -1, as the part of the original post was to just get a count of the number of comments and likes that matched the id.

Comment: tnx user3473534, i appreciate your help, perphaps i didn't explain  the problem in a clear way, my bad. by the way, i cant vote yet.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing I want to query all posts with their author name, number of likes and comments, and the post body in one query. This is how it been done.

## Using UNION

```
SELECT p.body, u.name, COUNT(lc.likes), COUNT(lc.comments)
FROM post p
JOIN user u ON p.uid=u.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pid, uid AS likes, NULL AS comments FROM like
    UNION
    SELECT pid, NULL, id FROM comment ) lc ON p.id = lc.pid
GROUP BY pid
```

I wrote this with the basic of SQL. You should know how to correct it if there is syntax error or so